# How to open multiple files matching a wildcard expression?

Tags: multiple-files

I want to edit several files matching a glob expression. For example, to edit all git config files in child directories, I can do this in the shell:

```
vim */.git/config
```

At the Vim `:` command line, I expected `:find */.git/config` to do something similar (i.e., open all files matching the glob expression), but instead it complains `E77: Too many file names`.

Is there Vim command or one-liner to open multiple files matching a wildcard/glob expression (that doesn't involve writing a function)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `:args {glob}`. In your glob, `**` will traverse directories recursively.

This will populate the argument list, which is the same list that gets populated when you start Vim with one or more filenames as arguments.

Once your argument list is populated, you can navigate through it using `:next` and `:previous`. You can also jump to the first and last item with the `:first` and `:last` commands.

Comment: Nice :) `:args */.git/config` actually populates the buffer list as well, so `:bnext` works too. Does that seem odd? (Vim 7.4.52, and Neovim)

Comment: Also a reminder to others, `]a` cycles the `:args` list if https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired is installed.

Comment: Also `:argadd file*` can do.

Comment: To use glob patterns (`**`), you need to have `globstar` set, see: [Match all files under all nested directories with shell globbing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4349082/55075).

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes The buffer list is a superset of the args list, so that's expected.

Answer (score 4):

> At the Vim `:` command line, I expected `:find */.git/config` to do something similar (i.e., open all files matching the glob expression), but instead it complains `E77: Too many file names`.

Don't expect anything before reading the documentation.

In addition to Tom's answer, you can directly use `:next` as an alternative to `:args`.

Comment: The edit history is incredible. And 7 yrs later, too.

Answer (score 4):

To open matching files in separate tabs…

```
:n */.git/config | tab all
```

<sub>**Explanation:**  `:n` (`:next`) sets the next-file list to all matches.  `tab all` opens all files in the next-file list in new tabs.</sub>

… or …

```
for f in glob("*.py", 0, 1) | exe "tabe" f | endfor
```

<sub>**Explanation:**  In `glob(…)`, the 0 means to include *all* matching files, even if they would otherwise be ignored due to the `suffixes` or `wildignorecase` settings.  The 1 means to return a list, instead of a string.  `exe "tabe" f` is a short form of `execute "tabedit" f` and means to open the file specified by the variable `f` in a new tab.</sub>

Comment: Looks like `:n */.git/config | buffer` works.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely covered already in other answers, but tl;dr

Open in buffers:
`:n <your-file-glob>`

Open in tabs:
`:n <your-file-glob> | tab all`

Open in windows:
`:n <your-file-glob> | ba`

For:

- VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jul 23 2020 16:01:01)
- Running on Linux (Clear Linux)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! If you don't mind me asking, is there a reason to summarize what's in the other answers?

Comment: Yep, just to get the most common methods one wants to use, done in the simplest fashion, all in one answer. I love the insights and details people provide but when all you want is the 'answer right now' because you have 10 more important things to be doing.... When you want to learn the in-depth detail, come back and read all the better answers and comments, across about 5 different questions of the same topic and you are good to go. Sometimes though, you just want clear and simple.

Comment: This one actually useful, thanks for summarizing!

Answer (score 0):

Opening files by `vim */.git/config` definitely should work. If it doesn't, you should upgrade your Vim to 7.4 (previous version was more buggy).

Alternatively try one of the following (within the editor):

```
:n `find .git/ -name config`
:args `find . -name config`
```

Comment: You didn't read my question carefully. And, the accepted answer already mentions `:args`.

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes Thanks for your points. Wildcard should work by default and this is the only answer which says that it should work in 7.4 (as I had exactly the same error before the upgrade). Using `args` is only the workaround, but further more it shows you how to use the shell expansion within vim it-self in case further users wants to use it for more complex solutions, by using `find`, such as [this one](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2997/467). So I think it gives some additional value to your question. So I hope it's fine with you.

Comment: I never had an issue with `vim */foo`, and there's no way that could be related to the Vim version, because that's a *shell* feature.

Answer (score -1):

Obvious , but not listed above - example find all the sql files having the create_table string in their name

```
:args **/*create_table*sql
```

and check them

```
:ls
```

and open the first one

```
:b 1
```