# Why vim cannot expand wildcards from the external command?

Tags: external-command, multiple-files

The following command works as expected within vim:

```
:args `find . -type f`
```

as well as this one (with wildcard):

```
:args `find . -name \*.inc`
```

However when I run the following:

```
:args `find . -type f -not -path "*/\.*"`
```

I've the error:

> E79: Cannot expand wildcards
>
> "`find . -type f -not -path" [New File]

It works from the command line as expected:

```
$ find . -type f -not -path "*/\.*"
```

Basically the extra `-not -path "*/\.*"` means to ignore all the hidden files starting with dot, such as git repository files.

What I'm doing wrong? Do some characters needs to be escaped (which one)?

Comment: More words about the E79. For this case, `find` returning error code let vim raise the E79 message.  This is not the same thing as `help E79` described. For instance, `:args \`false\`` also gets an E79, and it has nothing to do with expanding wildcard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were close. Enclose the path pattern in single quotes instead of double quotes for the find command like so:

```
args `find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*'`
```

By the way, a handy way to ignore hidden files is to use `:args **`. But this will include folders too.

I'm not completely sure why you need to enclose it in single quotes, I believe that Vim will evaluate the special characters inside double quotes. See [`:help expr-quote`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) and [`:help literal-string`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#literal-string). A single quote will treat the pattern as a literal string and prevent Vim evaluating special characters inside the quote.

In this case, since `\.` is one of the special characters Vim will evaluate in a double quoted string, I believe this was the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of single-quote, it was too close:) Regarding glob pattern (`**`) it works for bash and zsh, only when `globstar` is set, so sometimes it's not set by default. And it include also the folders. But it's a great substitute:) This one `{,**/}*.*` will exclude folders (bash4).

Comment: Yep, you're right, `args **` does include folders. You can always give it extensions (`:args *.h *.cpp` etc) to search for, so that it's both faster and will only find files. Amended my answer though.

Comment: Re: globstar, I've performed some small testing in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29731174/55075).

Comment: @kenorb, I am trying to run this command:  `vim /undo/g \`find /home/dibya \( -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex  '.*        vim|.*md' \)\``

Comment: However, it seems because of the `|`, vim gives me the same error you found. `E79: Cannot expand wildcards`. Is there a way to include  `|` in vimgrep commands?

Comment: @alpha_989 Have you tried to escape it (`\|`)?

Comment: @kenorb.. Thanks that worked great. I thought that wouldnt work because I was trying to do a _OR_ operation with `.*vim` and `.*md`. And `extended-regex` uses just `|` as the alternation operator. It seems like vim does look inside backtick expressions to check for special characters.. so `\|` actually evaluates to `|`.